# Using RDP in UBuntu Server Edition

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu Server Edition with no GUI. Is it possible to coonect to different computer using remote desktop conncetion on ubuntu server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not certain I understand your question, if you wish to connect from a GUI-less ubuntu server to a windows machine running a terminal server that is not possible without installing the X windowing system and the [rdesktop client](http://www.rdesktop.org/)

Doing this is not recommend on a production server due to increased complexity bringing greater security risk.

If you wish to connect to an ubuntu server instance from a desktop or another server for remote managment purposes, the [Secure Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) protocol (commonly known as SSH) is the most comment method.

You can connect to your server from your (presumably windows) desktop using an [SSH client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients) like [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

From there you can issue commands like you are infront of the machine, by default ubuntu server does not have an SSH server, the most widely adopted ssh server software for Ubuntu and other Linux based operating systems is [OpenSSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH), to install OpenSSH in ubuntu from the command line simple issue:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

There are of course other [SSH servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers)

Once an SSH server is running, you can connect to it using the host's ip address or hostname and TCP port 22.